# Babel not transpiling `class` in *.mjs files

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

Given

```
import test from './test.js';
import test2 from './test.mjs';
```

and `test.js` and `test.mjs` both containing

```
class A {
    test() {
        console.log('from mjs'); // or console.log('from js');
    }
}
export default A;
```

Babel transpiles

```
  [...];

  (0, _createClass2.default)(A, [{
    key: "test",
    value: function test() {
      console.log('from js');
    }
  }]);

  [...]

  class A {
    test() {
        console.log('from mjs');
    }
  }

  [...]
```

How should I configure babel to treat `*.mjs` files exactly like `*.js` files. I need them to be `*.mjs` files so that I can run it in `node` without transpilation.

Plugins I am currently explicitly adding are

```
'@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime', '@babel/plugin-transform-classes'
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Babel version: `7.0.0-beta.46`, and the last plugin is `transform-classes` or am I misunderstanding you? (I am sorry, my experience has been primarily with traceur before Babel won the transpiler wars)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Well, they have been moving everything to the `@babel` namespace. When you check the `es2015-classes` npm package the referenced github is a 404, as it has been moved to the new system.

Comment: Anyway, the class compilation clearly works by itself, it's just that somehow `*.mjs` files get treated different and thus not transpiled. I have been wondering whether it might have to do with https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/5700

Comment: Sounds like the plugin name was a red herring then. Good luck!

Comment: Is it not transforming the class syntax only, or nothing at all for the .mjs files? If the latter is true, you might want to check the babel-loader options in the webpack config to make sure it's also running babel against mjs files.

Comment: @ElianIbaj just classes, everything else is being transformed

Comment: could you share your webpack config?

Comment: @DavidMulder Almost two years later, I am having exactly the same problem. May I ask how you solved it? Thanks

Comment: @foresightyj read my answer below, hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `*.mjs` extension to your Webpack configuration:

```js
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            // ...
```